# Trying to achieve a very basic toolbar layout in Android - unexpected results

Tags: android, toolbar, android-toolbar

I'm aiming to have a toolbar with text in the center of it and a menu icon on the far left, like so:

!-ICON-----TEXT-----------!

This is how I have attempted it:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar_test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text Here"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/hamburger2"
        android:layout_gravity="left"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I found that without a RelativeLayout it displays ONLY the text. But as it stands, the toolbar looks like this:

!-TEXT-----ICON-----------!

For some reason it displays them in the wrong order. Even if I swap the layout_gravity of the 2 elements it displays the same thing.

Does anybody know why this could be happening?

Comment: Are you trying to add the hamburger menu in the toolbar then center text?

Comment: Are you using android studio or eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would accomplish this. Here is a link to all of the material icons. https://www.google.com/design/icons/  Make sure you are using their hamburger menu.  Also if you are using Android Studio, you should have 4 different sizes for the hamburger menu within your mipmap folder. Also, Tooolbar titles are 22sp

Here is what the toolbar would look like with the example below:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbarContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar_test"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/hamburger2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Text Here"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="23sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Rest of your Content -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbarContainer">

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're setting the width of your views to `match_parent`, which makes them as wide as the parent `RelativeLayout` and drawn on top of each other regardless of their positioning. The text appears to the left, because it's left-aligned by default and the image is centered for the same reason. You should set it to `wrap_content` to make them only as wide as needed.

Secondly, `android:layout_gravity` does not really work well with a `RelativeLayout`, because [gravity is applied on all its children at once after postioning](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html#setGravity%28int%29). You can use `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` for centering instead.

Besides that, when using a `RelativeLayout`, if you populate yout `TextView` with a long text, it might stretch and overlap the image. Please consider using a `LinearLayout`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar_test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/hamburger2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text Here"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="23sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

This way the text will be always displayed to the right of the image.